# Installing Ubuntu GNOME dual boot on Sony VAIO Pro, EFI problems

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, vaio

I recently bought a Sony VAIO Pro 13 and after witnessing the horror that in Windows 8, I decided to attempt to install Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 as a dual boot option.

During the install process I partitioned 2 drives: for the Ubuntu root mount and the swap area. The installation went fine and I restarted without the LiveUSB, however tHe laptop booted directly into Win 8. The install guide said I should see a GRUB menu but I didn't. After restarting back into the LiveUSB I ran the boot-repair utility using the recommended settings and then restarted. Now the laptop will not even boot into Windows, I get an "Operating system not found error" in both UEFI and Legacy modes.

Here is my boot-repair log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7064164/

I know there are some issues with the SSD and I have found info on how to fix this, providing you can at least boot to Grub, which I can't?!

Any help is appreciated, I am worried I have bricked this brand new laptop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I recommend you do, but I can make no guarantees that it will work:

1. Boot a Linux live CD.
2. Run Boot Repair again, but enter the Advanced setup area and select the option to restore backed-up files. When you tell it to complete this action, you should be back to where you were before (Windows should boot, but GRUB won't appear). Even if you can't boot Windows at this point, you can proceed at least through step #6 without risking anything.
3. [Disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) in your firmware.
4. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium with it.
5. Boot to the rEFInd medium.
6. rEFInd should detect both Windows and Ubuntu, and both should boot. (There will probably be more than one Ubuntu entry. As long as one boots, you're fine, but it's possible that the GRUB option will fail.)
7. If both Windows and Ubuntu boot, download and install the Debian-package version of rEFInd.

At this point, rEFInd should appear when you reboot the computer. If not, then your firmware is broken, and you'll need to experiment with workarounds, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) You can also post back with more details if you run into such problems.

Comment: Thanks Rod, the Boot Repair restore worked perfectly. I am cautious about installing rEFInd as I have read that the Sony VAIO Pro UEFI firmware kicks **only** "EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi" [Page 5 here](http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/27418512) so I will have to make sure I know what I'm doing before I play with that!

Comment: My process up to step #6 makes no changes to your computer, so the risk to that point is as close to 0 as you'll get. If step #7 fails because your firmware is buggily coded to boot only Windows, it should do no harm. If you run into such a problem, you can try a firmware update or [move/rename the rEFInd binary](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) to overcome the buggy firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the firmware boots only the EFI boot entry named `Windows Boot Manager`, so renaming your Linux boot entry to that will make it work in SecureBoot mode. It works for me.